# Maximum fixed genus Bipartite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

Say $B_{n,n}$ is a bipartite graph on $2n$ vertices with $n$ vertices of color $1$ and with $n$ vertices of color $2$.

What is the maximum number of edges that a genus $g$ graph $B_{n,n}$ can have? Are there any good references for this topic?

Comment: It's an easy exercise to show that if $B$ is simple and bipartite
and embeds in an orientable surface of genus $g$ then
$$
  |E(B)| \le 2|V(B)| - 4 + 4g
$$
and equality holds if and only if each face has degree four.

Comment: I think you can post it as an answer!!

Comment: Could you please provide a reference as well?

Answer (score 2):

Let's flesh out Chris Godsil's answer after the recent bump.

[Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) tells us that $V-E+F=2-2g$, where $V$, $E$ and $F$ are the number of vertices, edges and faces respectively in an embedding of $G$.  The smallest possible faces in an embedding of a bipartite graph are 4-cycles, so, by counting the edges round each face, $E \geq 4F/2$, i.e. $F \leq E/2$, with equality if and only if all faces are 4-cycles.  Rearranging gives $E \leq 2V -4 + 4g$.